# How to bind a property from an itemssource of one control to the "isExplanded" attribute of treeviewitem in xaml WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm using a treeview but not treeviewitem. Instead of treeviewitem I'm using "HierarchicalDataTemplate". Inside the "HierarchicalDataTemplate" I'm using Radiobutton to represent the tree view item. For styling I'm using the following code

```
<Style x:Key="keyName" TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
</Style>
```

Now I want to bind the isExpanded attribute of the above style with one of the properties from the ItemsSource of the "HierarchicalDataTemplate".

I tried the following code to achieve the same, but it's not working

```
<Style x:Key="keyName" TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=KeyNameOf_HierarchicalDataTemplate, Path=PropertyToBind, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It's simple. Just add the isExpanded binding inside the parent hierarchicaldatatemplate under "HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle" and by doing this you can control the isExpanded property by your binding variable.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classname:childclassname}" ItemsSource="{Binding bindingvariable>
                <RadioButton Name="btnRadio">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="Radio Button" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </Label>
                    </DockPanel>
                </RadioButton>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>                    
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding isExpandedBindingVariable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```